# is requiring "auto pay" for a better car insurence payment plan considered discrimination

Tags: automotive

my car insurance company doubles up my first monthly payment if i dont use auto pay.
is this considered discrimination. Why should I be penalized for not giving access to my bank account.....

Comment: You'll need to provide a jurisdiction for a useful answer, but I think we all know the answer already, which is that discrimination is legal, unless a law says otherwise. Discrimination on the basis of race is illegal; discrimination on the basis of payment structure is generally quite legal.

Comment: You also are likely not being "penalized" but rather willingly giving up a discount by choosing one payment alternative vs. the other.

Answer (score 6):

It may be discrimination, but it is not discrimination based upon any reason that the company is prohibited from engaging in. This conduct is legal in pretty much all U.S. jurisdictions.